# Add missing monthly rows

Tags: sql, hive, cassandra, hiveql, date-range

I would like to list the missing date between two dates in a request for example

My data :

```
YEAR_MONTH  | AMOUNT    
202001  |  500    
202001  |  600    
201912  |  100    
201910  |  200
201910  |  100     
201909  |  400
201601  | 5000
```

I want the request to return

```
201912  |  100    
201911  |    0    
201910  |  300
201909  |  400     
201908  |    0
201907  |    0
201906  |    0
....    |    0
201712  |    0
```

i want the last 24 months from the date of execution

I did something similar with the dates but not YEAR MONTH `yyyyMM`

```
select date_sub(s.date_order ,nvl(d.i,0)) as date_order, case when d.i > 0 then 0 else s.amount end as amount
from
(--find previous date
select date_order, amount, 
        lag(date_order) over(order by date_order) prev_date,
        datediff(date_order,lag(date_order) over(order by date_order)) datdiff
from
( --aggregate
 select date_order, sum(amount) amount from your_data group by date_order )s
)s
--generate rows
lateral view outer posexplode(split(space(s.datdiff-1),' ')) d as i,x
order by date_order;
```

I use Cassandra database with Apache Hive connector

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_range` subquery generates 24 months (adjust if you want some other than 24 months range) back from current date. Left join it with your dataset, see comments in this demo code:

```
with date_range as 
(--this query generates months range, check it's output
select date_format(add_months(concat(date_format(current_date,'yyyy-MM'),'-01'),-s.i),'yyyyMM') as year_month 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(24),' ')) as (i,x) ) s --24 months
),

your_data as (--use your table instead of this example
select stack(7,
202001, 500,    
202001, 600,    
201912, 100,    
201910, 200,
201910, 100,     
201909, 400,
201601,5000 -----this date is beyond 24 months, hence it is not in the output
) as (YEAR_MONTH, AMOUNT )
)

select d.year_month, sum(nvl(s.amount,0)) as amount --aggregate
  from date_range d 
       left join your_data s on d.year_month=s.year_month
  group by d.year_month;
```

Result:

```
d.year_month    amount
201801  0
201802  0
201803  0
201804  0
201805  0
201806  0
201807  0
201808  0
201809  0
201810  0
201811  0
201812  0
201901  0
201902  0
201903  0
201904  0
201905  0
201906  0
201907  0
201908  0
201909  400
201910  300
201911  0
201912  100
202001  1100
```

Use your table instead your_data subquery. Add `order by` if necessary.

Comment: What's `space(24)`? Can't find it in Spark SQL (neither in Scala's functions object nor in SQL mode)?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski This is Hive function, returns string of spaces with given length (24)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski in Scala/spark it should be more elegant ways of generating rows I believe. This is pure Hive sql

Comment: Does this `select posexplode(split(space(24),' ')) as (i,x)` generate 24 ids starting from 0?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski yes

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you'd like to add all dates that are currently missing because it so happened that `amount` was 0 at these days.

You can use this:

```
select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) base_date from
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
    having base_date between curdate() - interval 24 month and curdate();
```

This basically creates a list of dates between 1970 and 2200 (filtered for the ones you're interested in).

Idea is to select from this as a subquery and join with the table at hand (on the date field).

example of what this could look like: [return empty rows for not existsting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825829/return-empty-rows-for-not-existsting-data/59826573#59826573)

as for the date format (YEAR MONTH YYYYMM) you can run this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(your_date,'%Y%m')
```